# Loading multiple Youtube videos through the API without heavily affecting overall browser experience

Tags: angularjs, youtube-api, promise

When several Youtube videos are retrieved through the YouTubeAPI the browser "lags" due to the heavy task of loading the videos.

```
<div ng-repeat="video in videos" ng-controller="VideoCtrl">
   <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="video-wrapper" ng-class="{'loaded':video.player != undefined }" ng-mouseover="playVideo()" ng-mouseleave="pauseVideo()">
        <video-bg video-id="video.id" class="video" player-callback="callback(player)">
        ...
```

I would like the navigation and other functions of the page should not be affected (so much) during the loading process

I can't find a straightforward way to resolve this issue and I don't have sufficient knowledge of JS it seems. My app uses the [angular-video-bg](https://github.com/kanzelm3/angular-video-bg) directive

Thanks!